# Java ThreadPoolExecutor for indexing documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, threadpool, executorservice

I am new to Java `ThreaPoolExecutor` and I written some task to index documents in elastic search. Via `ThreaPoolExecutor` am executing that task and its working fine.

But, still am not very sure about my approach.

Please find my code below

```
public class IndexApp {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;

        System.out.println("Indexing via Java Code ....");
        Product prod1=new Product("1001", 123172l, "Product", "VG3000");
        Product prod2=new Product("1002", 123172l, "Series", "Valves, VG3000");
        Product prod3=new Product("1003", 3536633, "Series", "Activa RoofTop, VG3000 karthikeyan ");
        Product prod4=new Product("1004", 123172l, "Product", "Activa RoofTop VG3000, 3000");

        List<Product> objList=new ArrayList<Product>();
        objList.add(prod1);
        objList.add(prod2);
        objList.add(prod3);
        objList.add(prod4);

        for(int i=0;i<objList.size();i++)
        {
            jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            jsonMap.put("id", objList.get(i).getId());
            jsonMap.put("catalog_id", objList.get(i).getCatalog_id());
            jsonMap.put("catalog_type", objList.get(i).getCatalog_type());
            jsonMap.put("values", objList.get(i).getValues());
            IndexTask task = new IndexTask(jsonMap);
            executor.execute(task);
        }
         executor.shutdown();
    }

}


public class IndexTask implements Runnable {

private final static String INDEX_NAME = "index_prod";

Product prod=new Product();
IndexRequest request;
Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;

public IndexTask(Map<String, Object> jsonMap ) {
    this.jsonMap = jsonMap;
}

public Map<String, Object> getJsonMap() {
    return jsonMap;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Long duration = (long) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("Executing : "+jsonMap.get("id")+" Sleep Duration : "+duration );

        request = new IndexRequest(INDEX_NAME, "doc", jsonMap.get("id").toString() )
                .source(jsonMap);

        try {
            IndexResponse response = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().index(request); // increased timeout 
        } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
            if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Anyone let me know is my approach is meaning full for indexing documents in elastic search.?

**Update 2**

Please find my modified code.

Instead of using `IndexRequest` i used `BulkRequest`

```
public class ProdCatIndexTask implements Runnable {

    private final static String INDEX_NAME = "productcatalog_index";

    Product prod=new Product();
    IndexRequest request;
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;

    BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();

    public ProdCatIndexTask(Map<String, Object> jsonMap ) {
        this.jsonMap = jsonMap;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getJsonMap() {
        return jsonMap;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Long duration = (long) (Math.random() * 10);
            System.out.println("Executing : "+jsonMap.get("id")+" Sleep Duration : "+duration );

            /*request = new IndexRequest(INDEX_NAME, "doc", jsonMap.get("id").toString() )
                    .source(jsonMap);*/

            bulkRequest.add( new IndexRequest(INDEX_NAME, "doc", jsonMap.get("id").toString()).source(jsonMap));

            try {
                //IndexResponse response = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().index(request); // increased timeout
                BulkResponse bulkResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().bulk(bulkRequest);
                System.out.println("Triggered Bulk Request.....");
            } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
                if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is probably a bit opinion based... The overall approach is valid in and of itself. But if you thread, you're probably aiming for performance, therefore, I'd suggest 2 improvements. 1) Do the maximum of the processing in the tasks (that includes formatting the request objects / maps). 2) Use the bulk indexing API of elastic search, it is made for mass indexing. At 4 elements at a time, you won't see much of a difference. At 40 thousands, you *will*. Finally : do not ignore the possible failures of the tasks; look à the `Future` objects returned by `.execute(task)`.

Comment: @GPI - I have changed the code by using `IndexRequest` to `BulkRequest`. But it was triggering 4 times, when am trying to insert 4 documents into the index. Am expecting to trigger that `BuldRequest` only once for all 4 documents to be indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load data in bulk mode in parallel, I recommend using ElasticSearch API `BulkProcessor`.

Here is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk-processor.html.

Example how to use bulkProcessor:

```
bulkProcessor.add(new IndexRequest("indexName", "type")
.source(toJson(Product), XContentType.JSON);
```

If you want to make faster, you can reduce the number of the replica to 0 and let ElasticSearch generate ID's, because if you indexing your own ID, each time ElasticSearch checks if this ID's exists in ElasticSearch.

Other ideas about how to increase loading performance:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html